# Wrap html content within webview vertically with no horizontalscrollbar?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, webview

I am working on a HTML page reader in android and have to give similar functionality like eBook reader ,here i am facing one problem so please tell me how can i wrap the content within the width of web-view (that i am using fill-parent in XML) on zooming or scale i.e the content should increase in height(vertically) not width(No Horizontal-wise scroll bar) so the content should flow downside width will always be fixed of same i.e 700 dp

> > Here in android web-view i want to zoom the page by programming but nothing I am getting >for zoom so I am scaling the web-view i.e on
> >     click of button increase the scale and
> >     refresh the page and I have the option of re flow if I select that so
> >     all pages are joint together as a one page and all scrolling is
> >     disable here .Here i am having a next button on clicking on that I
> >     will scroll down so if am zooming in re-flow so the content should be
> >     always wrap and should be visible within the web view height so 
> >     Please tell me any solution or step to solve this issue.

Here after increase scaling the content is going out of web view width and not visible because no horizontal scroll is there

Comment: sorry for any mistake and please provide me the solution instead of decrementing my points

Comment: Do you want the text size to increase when the user does a pinch-to-zoom gesture? Or will you provide buttons or other controls for zooming?

Comment: Hello Nathan Manousos i am trying to zoom via button(Zoom in,zoom out)

Comment: Does simply increasing the font size of the page not work?

Comment: No the HTML content is going outside the boundary of webview